# How does output level of food grains and industrial goods go together? My textbook doesn't give many details but I'm curious to know

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request

If we observe the economy of a country as a whole it will appear that the output levels of all the goods and services in the economy have a tendency to move together. For example, if output of food grain is experiencing a growth, it is generally accompanied by a rise in the output level of
industrial goods.

Comment: It's actually not true that the levels of *all* the goods and services an economy produces move together. In fact, the composition changes all the time. The production of typewriters is nowadays close to zero! Maybe you can clarify what exactly you mean? Are you referring to aggregate levels of goods vs services? And what exactly to you mean by "move together"? That would help answering the question.